# Probability Formula for Posterior With 3 Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayes-theorem

First post on math.stackexchange; pardon me if this is naive/a repeat.

I'm following this document here by Prof. David M. Blei: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf

In this, I don't quite understand how he arrived at the posterior distribution formula for p(u, z|x) under section "Motivation" - bullet number 3.

I'm trying to think in terms of vectors. I also know that the formula makes an independence assumption between the individual components of vectors x and z (hence the multiplications with subscript 'i'). I also know that the denominator is p(x), since u and z are obviously being "integrated out". Also, u is a continuous parameter, z is discrete. Hence the integral and the summation in the denominator respectively.

But let's focus only on the numerator right now. The first term, is obviously p(u) (or is it?). **The second term is what I'm not able to understand. Is it some form of p(x, z | u)?**

**Another question:** In the "Set up" section - bullet 2, the posterior is defined as p(z | x, α). Note how the α is on the **right hand side** of the "|".
Now, in section "Motivation" - bullet 3, the posterior is defined as p(µ1:K, z1:n | x1:n). A fair assumption (IMO) to make is that α = µ1:K, i.e. the parameters of this model. How did α jump to the **left hand side** of the "|" in this definition of the posterior then?

***Note:*** The notation used in the above question is as follows:

u : mu, the parameters of the Gaussian distribution assumed.

x : a vector of variables, say x_i, where i = 1:N

z : latent variables associated with each x above. This is also a vector of dimension M.

Thanks, and any/all help is appreciated!

Comment: Also, why isn't there a tag called "posterior-distribution"? :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's take a step back: when we only have two variables, we know the posterior could be written as $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}$. In this case, when we have three variables, let's first treat ($\mu$,$z$) as a whole: $$P(\mu,z|x) = \frac{P(x|\mu,z)P(\mu,z)}{P(x)} $$ Since $\mu$ and $z$ are independent, it could also be written as $$P(\mu,z|x) = \frac{P(\mu)P(z)P(x|\mu,z)}{P(x)}$$ As $\mu$ is a K-dimensional vector, and both $z$ and $x$ are $n$-dimensional vectors, then the latter two could share a product operator from 1 to $n$.
2. The hyperparameter $\alpha$ is $\pi$ in this derivation, but it is omitted in those expressions. It appears as "Mult($\pi$)" in the second bullet point of "2. Motivation" section. $\pi$ is the K-dimensional vector of cluster weights. That being said, the value of each element in $z$ ranges from 1 to K (or 0 to K-1 if you prefer 0-index).